# Prevent duplicated rows in MySQL table in scalable environment

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, microservices

I have an Employees **MySQL** table in my project and **10 instances** of a **SpringBoot** application each of which can populate data to it. Table looks as follows...

```
ID  |  FirstName  | LastName
------------------------------ 
1   |  Aaa        | Aaaa 
2   |  Bbb        | Bbbb 
3   |  Ccc        | Cccc
```

I want to ensure, it is **impossible to insert** any other entity with **already existing FirstName/LastName pair**.

Options I can see is (but not sure if correct):

- Make a **select** first and, if not results, perform **insert** (but in this case I have no guarantee that other instance of populating application will not add the row meanwhile - race condition)
- using **locks** on the table
- **handling exceptions** when inserting data vialoting constraint limitations - not nice cause generates hibernate errors in logs

Questions:

- What **other options** should I consider in such case?
- What is the **most
  common approach** to prevent duplicated rows in multi-instance
  environments?

Comment: Create a unique index on `(FirstName, LastName)`. If you try to create a duplicate you'll get an error.

Comment: *I want to ensure, it is impossible to insert any other entity with already existing FirstName/LastName pair.* But complete namesakes exists...

Comment: @Barmar this is actually one possible solution I'm considering but I wanted to avoid "exception driven" development - that's why was thinking if there is any more elegant solution

Comment: If you consider exception handling a problem then there's no "elegant" solution. You can solve the race condition in the first option by using transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use exception handling. This is an ordinary and common practice in programming. Your question was what is the *most common solution,* and this is it.

If you want to minimize the number of exceptions, then use a select to check for the name first. That creates a race condition, as you know, so you would still have to catch the exception. But it should avoid most of the conflicts.

I don't know why Hibernate would log anything if you handle the exception. That sounds unlikely to me, but I am not a Hibernate developer, so I don't know if there's a way to prevent that logging.

Using a table lock would also avoid the exception, but it restricts concurrent inserts, so it's not a good solution if you have a high traffic rate.

Comment: Actually, the most common solution in my experience is that many programmers don't do anything to prevent duplicates at all.